# How to disable "bring activity to front" in android launch?

Tags: android, libgdx, warnings

I code games for android with **LibGDX**.
In **LibGDX** you code in the core project, but compile the android project to run the game.so android project have no change in code at all.
so when I try to run the project in android, compiler always gives me :

> "Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to
>   the front"

and installs nothing because of no change in android code.Of course if I uninstall the app or change the android code, there's no problem.but this is a time-taking process.
Is there anyway to disable this feature? or any other solution?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? You can try checking "build automatically" in one of the menus (don't remember which). Or save yourself many, many hours of frustration by switching to IntelliJ. I used to fight through many types of issues like this in Eclipse, and I really kick myself that I didn't make the switch to IntelliJ much sooner.

Answer (score -1):

unInstall Current APK. and Then run new apk from eclipse

Comment: It is more like comment than real answer.

Comment: problem is not "it won't install". problem is every time I should uninstall app or change android code a little. this is a time-taking process.question edited